# How to make PHP surveys compulsory before displaying the next one

Tags: php, html, forms, survey

I have the following problem: I have a few surveys on my app (see the following code), but when I run it, all the surveys display at the same time. I want that at first it only appears the first survey, when you need to select an event, then I want the second survey selecting between adding, deleting, modifying information or see the event information and then the following ones. Here is some the code, just 2 php with 2 surveys, which are displayed at the same time:

app.php

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Events Organizer-App</title>
 </head>
  <body background="eventxd.png" >
    <h1>Events Organizer App</h1> 
    <h2>Select the Event you are interested in...</h2>
 </body>
<form action="button.php" method="choose" target="page">
<input type="submit" name="Event1" value="Techno Party"> 
<input type="submit" name="Event2" value="College Dinner"> 
<input type="submit" name="Event3" value="City Tour"> 
<input type="submit" name="Event4" value="Comic Fair"> 
</form>
<iframe name="page" src="button.php"> //llamada al button.php
</iframe>
```

button.php

```
<?php

$Event1="";
$Event2="";
$Event3="";
$Event4="";
      //filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'var_name') en lugar de _Post[variable]
     //filter_input_array(INPUT_POST) instead of $_POST 
     if(isset($_GET['Event1'])) $Event1=$_GET['Event1'];
     if(isset($_GET['Event2'])) $Event2=$_GET['Event2'];
     if(isset($_GET['Event3'])) $Event3=$_GET['Event3'];
     if(isset($_GET['Event4'])) $Event4=$_GET['Event4'];


    $Dir=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    $Dir="$Dir/base_event.txt"; 
    $ev_id=0;
   if($Event1){
     $ev_id=1;
   }

 if($Event2){
   $ev_id=2;     
 }

 if($Event3){
   $ev_id=3;    
 }

if($Event4){
   $ev_id=4;
 }


 <html>
 <body>
    <h1>Select one option...</h1> 
  </body>
 <form action="button2.php" method="choose" target="page">
 <input type="submit" name="Add" value="Participate on the event"> 
 <input type="submit" name="Erase" value="Erase my confirmation"> 
 <input type="submit" name="Info" value="See the event information"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="Dir" value="<?php echo $Dir; ?>">  
    <input type="hidden" name="ev_id" value="<?php echo $ev_id; ?>"> 
 </form>
 <iframe name="page" src="button2.php"> //llamada al botton.php
 </iframe>
 </html>
```

So I just want to know how to make this second survey "wait" until the first one is done to be displayed.

Comment: Is it necessary for the other form to be in an iframe? Can it be on a different page or it must all be on the same one?

Comment: I don´t understand your comment. Could you explain it a little bit please?

Comment: Let's try it this way: currently you're including your `button.php` and `button2.php` through iframe elements. Are you allowed to change the html structure or do you must use iframes? There are better ways to structure your html and program flow.

Comment: I can change it. I just want something simple to make the app better looking.